# Does an else if statement exist?

Tags: c, if-statement, language-lawyer, semantics

Some time ago after not standing anymore lines like this:

```
if (arg)
    invk(test);
else if (test)
{
    alot();
    stuff();
}
```

I decided for my self its better for readability in our 1920x1200 times, to not omit the `{}`.

So I wrote a tool that reformats my existing code.

later I noticed a bug in that tool resulting in

```
if (x)
{
 ...
}
else if(y)
{
 ...
}
else if(z)
{
 ...
}
```

had been changed (wihtout obvisiously changing the behavior) into:

```
if (x)
{
 ...
}
else 
{
    if(y)
    {
     ...
    }
    else
    {
        if(z)
        {
         ...
        }
    }
}
```

This made me realize (unintended) that this is actually what a `else if` does by syntax and semantical rules of C.

So is there even an statement like `else if()` existing or is it just an abuse of semantic that results in this usefull but (lets call it so for this purpose) obfuscation originated wording that breaks any formating rules and just serves as human readable?

Comment: No, `else if` is just another `if` following `else`. I think there's a duplicate of this question.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: What you mean by exclusive. I'm not getting why it shouldn't be. But I'd love to get enlighted.

Comment: No, but there is #elif

Comment: @technosaurus: This is s nonsense and missleading comment. You confuse core language and preprocessor.

Comment: I would not use a *code formatting tool* that inserts `{` between `else` and `if()`. Never.

Comment: @wildplasser: ofc one should do it never. But I made multiple times clear that this was a bug of my tool, which made me realize this. It never was intended to do so.

Comment: @Olaf It is misleading, I've seen new programmers see it in an #ifdef and make the assumption that its semantics can be carried over by removing the # as in #if and #else... usually its the ones with good deductive reasoning skills that make this leap.  And BTW the preprocessor _is_ part of the core language "6.10 Preprocessing directives"

Comment: @technosaurus: The standard does not use the term "core language". It is commonly the part processed after the preprocessing stages, i.e. after phase 4.

Comment: @Zaibis _not exclusive_ : forget this comment, it's stupid, I removed it.

Comment: @technosaurus I'm afraid people with good reasoning skills who are expecting a rationally-designed, consistent programming language are in for quite a bit of disappointment when it comes to C...

Comment: The distinction between the preprocessor language (with the `#elif` keyword) and the "core" C language (without a dedicated `else if` keyword) is actually very interesting to make. I see it as a result of C language having exactly 1 statement inside its `if` and `else` clauses, and the preprocessor having several lines inside `#if`, `#elif` and `#else` parts. I guess all languages take one of these two approaches, with Python going one way, Pascal going the other, and C going both ways :) A language-design rule of thumb: if you have some sort of `endif`, you should have some sort of `elseif`.

Comment: @anatolyg: interesting note. thanks for sharing it.

Comment: note that some languages do have an elseif - PHP for example

Comment: @pm100: Generally languages that use an `end`, `endif`, `end if`, or `fi` marker to terminate an `if` statement need a separate `elsif` or `elseif` keyword to avoid deep nesting. (But PHP doesn't, and `elseif` seems to be equivalent to `else if`.)

Comment: @pm100: note that im actually explicit asking about c

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As per the `C11`, chapter §6.8.4, *selection statements*, the available statement blocks are

```
if ( expression ) statement
if ( expression ) statement else statement
switch ( expression ) statement
```

and, regarding the `else` part,

> An `else` is associated with the lexically nearest preceding `if` that is allowed by the
>   syntax.

So, there is no `else if` construct, exists as per standard `C`.

Obviously, an `if` (or `if...else`) block can exist as the *statement* in `else` block (nested `if...else`, we may say).

The choice of indentation , is left to the user.

---

***Note:***

*Just to add, there is no reason for a separate `else if` construct to exist, the functionality can be achieved by nesting. See [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_(computer_programming)#Choice_system_cross_reference). Relevant quote*

> *The often-encountered `else if` in the `C` family of languages, and in COBOL and Haskell, is not a language feature but a set of nested and independent **"if then else"** statements combined with a particular source code layout. However, this also means that a distinct `else-if` construct is not really needed in these languages.*

Answer (score 3):

As every one is aware, there is several different styles of programming languages. The presence of a **elseif** is based on the style of language.
In a C/Pascal style the **if** statement is

```
if (...)
   statment; 
else
   statement;
```

and you have a compound statement:
    {
       statment;
       statment;
    }

while in a Modula2 / VB / (python ?) style language you have

```
if (...)
   statement;
   ...
   statement;
else
   statement;
   ...
   statement;
end-if
```

in the Modula2 / VB you **need** a **elseif** statement because if you tried using *else if* you get

```
if (..)
else if (..)
else if (..)
end-if; end-if; end-if;
```

The **end-if's** at the end are rather ugly.

As @anatolyg noted this is why you have a #elif in C macro language.

---

Cobol-85 has a different take on the elseif statement. It provides an extended *Select*/*case* statement. In Cobol you have an evaluate:

```
evaluate option
   when 1
      ...
   when 2
      ...
```

but you can also do

```
evaluate true
   when age > 21 and gender = 'male'
      ...
   when age > 21 and gender = 'female'
```

In Cobol you can also mix the case and if structure

```
evaluate option also true
   when 1 also age > 21 and gender = 'male'
      .... 
   when 1 also age > 21 and gender = 'female'
      .... 
   when 2 also any
      ....
```

---

One final point in java and C you sometimes see

```
if () {

} else if () {

} else if () {

}
```

To all intents and purposes, this is VB / Modula-2 written in Java/C.